# Custom Button Return URL (retURL)

Tags: custom-button, visual-workflow

I am using a custom button to execute a flow and a retURL tag to return to the record after the flow has been completed.

/flow/SAMPLEFLOW?RecID={!OBJECT.Id}&retURL=https://na10.salesforce.com/{!OBJECT.Id}

The button is currently set to display in the current window w/o header or sidebar.

I would like to set the custom button to display w/o a sidebar BUT WITH THE HEADER

Does anyone know of any URL parameters I can pass in to the retURL to return to said URL but without a side bar or header.

This is to prevent the frame in frame look - Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I reckon `isdtp=vw` (the [magic service console parameter](http://www.ca-peterson.com/2011/11/magic-isdtp-param.html?m=1)) should do it.

Comment: I'm not saying this is answer is wrong since it definitely does work, but just in case someone doesn't read the blog post, they should be aware of the following from it "this is 100% unsupported and you should avoid using this whenever possible."  In other words, it isn't a SF published way of doing it.

Comment: I would support @techtrekker since after a lot of looking around I found that isdtp is the only savior. Again as pointed by peter there is no support offered by SF, but at the end isdtp gets the job done for now !!!

Comment: Thanks guys - warning is recognized. I already use some URL hacking and understand that it is not supported by SFDC. Great find though @techtrekker

Comment: Author of the post reporting in, while officially unsupported just about everybody and their brother uses this somewhere, so SF is going to be pretty much forced to at least notify customers when it will break.

Comment: Also as a tip you can use `retURL=%2F{!OBJECT.Id}` and/or `&saveURL=%2F{!OBJECT.Id}` to make your custom url more break-proof. If your instance (naX) ever changes or if you move a link from sandbox to production, etc. it will help you out.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to embed the Flow in a visualforce page and have your button call your page. When you embed your flow there's a completion attribute you can assign to return the user when the flow is completed.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_flows_adding.htm

Comment: So from your knowledge there is not a URL parameter to rid of the sidebar and header?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set retUrl like this :

`/flow/SAMPLEFLOW?RecID={!OBJECT.Id}&retURL={!OBJECT.Id}`

Comment: `Field OBJECT.Id does not exist.` when creating a List Button