# retURL not working on Custom Link that triggers Flow

Tags: custom-link

I have a custom link to trigger a FLOW to delete multiple records that are related to Case Object record.

My FLOW works to delete multiple records as expected and my Custom Link is set to "Display in existing window without sidebar or header" in Behavior. It deletes multiple records from a  listview.

But the retURL on the Custom Link does not seem to work when FLOW finish.
I want users to go back to the Case related Object Record or related CASE record.
Currently it goes back to the FLOW starting screen to ask "Are you sure you want to delete these records?" screen instead.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_internal_url_retURL.htm&type=5

https://dfc-org-production.force.com/forums/?id=9062I000000UfemQAC

I have reviewed multiple relevant references like above and tried below (all without syntax error), but none seem to return to the URL I want when FLOW finishes. Any suggestions how I can achieve the retURL?

```
/flow/(flowAPIname)?retURL=/a28/o

/flow/(flowAPIname)?retURL=/a28/o/(ObjectAPIname)/list?filterName=00B8b00000AKCv0xxx (Object's view all listview)

/flow/(flowAPIname)?retURL=/r/Case/

/flow/(flowAPIname)?retURL=/lightning/o/Case/list?filterName=Recent

/flow/(flowAPIname)? retURL=/{ObjectAPIname.Id}

/flow/(flowAPIname)? saveURL=%2F{ObjectAPIname.Id}

/flow/(flowAPIname)?retURL=a28?fcf=00B8b00000AKCv0xxx (Object's view all listview)

/flow/(flowAPIname)?retURL=/lightning/o/ObjectAPIname/list?filterName=00B8b00000AKCv0xxx (Object's view all listview)

/flow/(flowAPIname)?retURL=/lightning/o/ObjectAPIname/list?filterName=Recent
```

I appreciate your time for reading this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Do any of these help? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/303303/81648 | https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/333423/81648 | https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/350721/81648 | https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/301086/81648

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is due to flow lightning runtime. Please follow the below steps to disable it.

1. From Setup, enter Process Automation Settings in the Quick Find box, then select Process Automation Settings.
2. Select Enable Lightning runtime for flows. (Untick it)
3. Save your changes.